# Get matches between two dataframes in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

EDIT: Realized I might have already asked a very similar question, testing to see if that solution works.

Is there a way to get the matches from two dataframes without using `pandas.merge`?

I've been using this: `pd.merge(dfa, dfb, on=('A', 'B', 'C'), how='right')`, but it doesn't work how I would expect it to.

I have two dataframes, one that is like this:

```
A     B     C
w     1     1
b     1     2
c     3     1
c     3     1
```

and the second looking like

```
A     B     C    D
w     1     1    1/1/14
b     1     2    1/3/14
c     3     1    1/7/14
c     3     1    1/7/14
d     4     7    1/7/14
z     5     3    1/8/14
```

The first dataframe has been run through a query using `pandasql`, and for some reason `pandasql` has trouble handling dates even if they're not being used in the query (I get `Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.` even when it's not being used)

What I want in the end is

```
A     B     C    D
w     1     1    1/1/14
b     1     2    1/3/14
c     3     1    1/7/14
c     3     1    1/7/14
```

but when I use `pandas.merge`, I end up with

```
A     B     C    D
w     1     1    1/1/14
b     1     2    1/3/14
c     3     1    1/7/14
c     3     1    1/7/14
c     3     1    1/7/14
c     3     1    1/8/14
```

no matter if I use inner, right or left for `how`.

I was hoping I would just be able to use `pandasql` and skip all this by some kind of date parsing option but I can't seem to find any.

So, is there another way to do this that isn't `pandas.merge` or looping through all the columns/rows of the dataframes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will `concat` with `inner` option handle the case for you, if your dataframes are already matched?

```
In [46]:

print pd.concat((df1, df2), join='inner', axis=1)[[0,1,2,-1]]
   A  B  C       D
0  w  1  1  1/1/14
1  b  1  2  1/3/14
2  c  3  1  1/7/14
3  c  3  1  1/7/14
```

`[[0,1,2,-1]]` is to avoid the duplicating `A`, `B` and `C` columns

Anyway, this may be a better and more general solution:

```
In [90]:

print pd.merge(df1.drop_duplicates(subset=['A', 'B', 'C']),
               df2, on=['A','B','C'])
   A  B  C       D
0  w  1  1  1/1/14
1  b  1  2  1/3/14
2  c  3  1  1/7/14
3  c  3  1  1/7/14
```

Comment: Sometimes. Doesn't work when df1 is only one row, but seems to work besides that. going to test with some more data, but seems to be the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I am just about to delete it as it won't work unless `A`, `B`, `C` are already matched up. But let's come back to revisit it later. I really suspect the issue is due to the duplicated rows.

Comment: It's actually working for me, so far. The problems with my other attempts have been duplicates each getting matched twice, causing there to be 4 instead of 2.

Comment: I just edited the answer with a more general solution. `drop_duplicate` in one `df` will get around it.